# Drop down menus in tabs

Tags: oracle-apex

Is possible to create a dropdown menu in tabs like the ones in the configuration of apex:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see [this plug-in component](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/region-plugin/jquery-menu_82.html)

Comment: i'm tring to put the menus attached to existing page tabs but is giving erros like this:
`SELECT /* Page Tabs */
id ,  pid, text, url,  display_seq
FROM   SURV_MENU
WHERE  application_id       = :APP_ID
AND    list_name = :LIST_NAME
AND    auth_condition_check
      ( p_condition_type        => condition_type
      , p_condition_expression1 => condition_expression1
      , p_condition_expression2 => condition_expression2
      , p_authorization_scheme  => authorization_scheme
      ) = 0`

    ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea why.

Comment: And you know if it is possible to put the menu attached to bar of page tabs?

Comment: You can put it where you want on the page by changing the page template.

Comment: Can you help with that, i'm in standard tab attributes but i dont what to change

Comment: You can't use this solution as part of standard Apex tabs; you can use this solution **instead of** Apex tabs.

Comment: So i have to remove the Apex bar from template?

Comment: You could do that yes, and put a region position e.g. #REGION_POSITION_01# in that place, then assign your new menu region to that position.

Comment: do you know any manual too edit templates i'm having some problems